# Android custom spinner doesn't show the dropdown arrow

Tags: android, android-spinner

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/

In this example above, before an item is selected it shows text and dropdown arrow on the right. When the user clicks it (displaymode = dropdown?) it shows the prompt with an arrow as well. This is the behavior I want my customer spinner to do, but it's not. Primarily I want the spinner to load with wtih the normal dropdown arrow as first item. The prmpt issue I can at least get text to appear if i set displaymode=dialog on the spinner. For this post I mostly would like to get the default item issue resolved first...

Info:
I do not have android theme on my app. My parent systel is AppTheme butno parent above that. I have custom spinner like so:

```
        List<LanguageSelection> nativeLanguagesData = getSupportedLanguageList();
    LanguageSelectionListAdapter nativeAdapter = new LanguageSelectionListAdapter (this, R.layout.fragment_language_selection, nativeLanguagesData);
    nativeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
    Spinner uxNativeLanguageSpinner  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.uxNativeLanguageSpinner);
    uxNativeLanguageSpinner.setAdapter(nativeAdapter);
```

and for xml:

```
            <Spinner android:id="@+id/uxNativeLanguageSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" 
        android:prompt="@string/status_prompt"
        android:layout_below="@id/uxNativeLanguageSelectLabel"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Attached is what appears. I've scoured the internet trying to figure out why this thing doesn't show first item with arrow. I also have the android simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml in my code base instead of referencing andorid.r.*. Any ideas? I'd like to get rid of my ugly label just above the spinner indicating the user needs to select something and instead use the common dropdown arrow on the first item. Just doesn't show when I create a custom spinner though. Again, the items in the list appear correctly it's just that i want the first item be something like in the link at the top where there is Select and iten and down arrow icon to the right indicating it's dropdown.

[http://tinypic.com/r/2r7927o/5][1]

And this is image link below shows exactly what I'm talking about. I circled in red the dropdown arrow I want to appear. I want my list to appear just like this and it except for the dropdown arrow. The actual list of items when clicked appear just fine...

tinypic.com/r/2ekj6mv/5 (sorry, can't hyperlink because i need 10 reps to post two links)

Comment: If you post a link to the image, another user will happily edit your post for you with the actual image tag!

Comment: host the image somewhere and post the link so we can see it

Comment: put link, ill change it to image

Comment: Here's the link while I try to figure out how to edit my post in the mean time. Thaks for the fast response! http://tinypic.com/r/2r7927o/5